# Computed observable not updating UI

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, computed-observable

I have a problem with a computed variable in my knockout web. Here's my code:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.seatsRaw = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedSeatId = ko.observable();
    self.session = ko.observable();
    self.seats = ko.computed(function(){
        var seatsComplete= self.seatsRaw().slice(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < seatsComplete.length; i++) {
            if (self.selectedSeatId()) {
                seatsComplete[i].selected = seatsComplete[i].id == self.selectedSeatId();
            } else if (self.session () && Number(self.session ().seat) > 0) {
                seatsComplete[i].selected = seatsComplete[i].id == self.sesion().seat;
            } else {
                seatsComplete[i].selected = false;
            }
        }
        return seatsComplete;
    });
    self.selectSeat = function(data,event) {
    self.selectedSeatId($(this).id);
    };
}
```

So, I just receive an array with seats and I want to add a field to each object in array to show in the UI as "selected".

I read from ajax the info for session and seats raw, and when I update them I don't see any change in my UI.

Why is happening? And then, what I need to do to update my UI?

Thanks!

EDIT

```
<ul class="seats" data-bind="foreach: seats">
      <li data-bind="css: {selected: selected, 'non-selected': !selected}, click: $root.selectSeat">
       <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {id: id}">
            <img data-bind="attr: {src: baseUrl + 'img/seats/' + image}" />
            <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
       </a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Seat is not a ViewModel... should it be?

Comment: The `selected` property in `seatsComplete` does probably have to be observable. Which means you have to set it using `seatsComplete[i].selected(seatsComplete[i].id == self.selectedSeatId())` etc.

Comment: Sorry, that is not working...

Comment: Can you show your view (HTML) and the seat's viewmodel?

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing some extra context. I'll try to explain a bit better what I meant in the comments.

> Seat is not a ViewModel... should it be?

Even when a `Seat` is just a plain object, it's also kind of a viewmodel... Here's what's happening in your code (as far as I can tell):

When you're creating the new array in your computed, it gets filled with *the same objects the previous array had*. The knockout renderer doesn't see a reason to re-render the list items.

Check out this example. From the logs you see everything "working correctly", but knockout won't update. After this example, I'll show what happens if we make `selected` observable.

```js
var seats =[
  { id: 1, selected: false },
  { id: 2, selected: true },
  { id: 3, selected: false }
];

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.rawSeats = ko.observableArray(seats);
  
  this.selectedSeatId = ko.observable(2);
  this.selectSeat = function(data, event) {
    self.selectedSeatId(data.id)
  }
  
  this.seats = ko.computed(function() {
    var selectedId = self.selectedSeatId();
    self.rawSeats().forEach(function(seat) {
      seat.selected = seat.id === selectedId;
    })
    
    console.log(self.rawSeats());
    return self.rawSeats();
    
  });
  
  }

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
.selected { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: seats">
  <li data-bind="css: { selected: selected }, 
                 text: id,
                 click: $root.selectSeat"></li>
</ul>
```

**Now, with observable properties:**

```js
var seats =[
  { id: 1, selected: ko.observable(false) },
  { id: 2, selected: ko.observable(true) },
  { id: 3, selected: ko.observable(false) }
];

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.rawSeats = ko.observableArray(seats);
  
  this.selectedSeatId = ko.observable(2);
  this.selectSeat = function(data, event) {
    self.selectedSeatId(data.id)
  }
  
  this.seats = ko.computed(function() {
    var selectedId = self.selectedSeatId();
    self.rawSeats().forEach(function(seat) {
      seat.selected(seat.id === selectedId);
    })
    
    return self.rawSeats();
    
  });
  
  }

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
.selected { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: seats">
  <li data-bind="css: { selected: selected }, 
                 text: id,
                 click: $root.selectSeat"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you run your code you'll see that the even if you change your viewmodel clicking on li's, the yellow background is always in the second li.

Comment: Did you read all the way to the second example...? The first one was meant to be broken to show the error I believe you've made...